# Postgres crosstab?

Tags: postgresql

Хочу создать представление. Примерно такая база

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у `analiz_create` несколько записей в `analiz_data`. И нужно "перевернуть" выборку, чтобы получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD**

Что-то мне подсказывает, что нужно использовать `crosstab`, но вот

```
select *  from crosstab('SELECT 
                            t1.value,
                            t2.name
                          FROM 
                            analiz_data t1,
                            element t2
                          WHERE
                            t1.elem_id = t2.id   ')
            as (value text, name text);
```

Пишет

> ERROR:  invalid source data SQL statement DETAIL:  The provided SQL
>   must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.

Comment: Что вы пробовали и что у вас не получилось? PS. Вообще обычно такие запросы делаются через join. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select * from 
    crosstab('SELECT 
            t1.analiz_id,
            t1.elem_id,
              t1.value
            FROM 
              a_analiz_data t1
            WHERE
              t1.analiz_id =36
                            ', //analiz_id - общий ид, 
            //elem_id - имя элемента
            //value - отображаемое значение
    '       SELECT 
  elem_id //elem_id - категория по которой группируются элементы. необходима для точного отображения в выборке
    FROM 
    a_analiz_data t1
  WHERE                            
     t1.analiz_id = 36')
  as (rowid int, att1 text, att2 text, att3 text, att4 text, att5 text, att6 text, att7 text);
```

было

```
    SELECT 
  t1.value,
  t1.elem_id
FROM 
  a_analiz_data t1
WHERE
  t1.analiz_id =36
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]